# How to fix TypeScript errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Start learning typescript few days ago, аnd so far, it's all hell for me) I hope it's worth it. Looks easy when I read about TS, and very, very hard to write anything right - now each correction just generates more, and more TS errors. Sorry, for that introduction :)

I have function (code below), and got few errors, and have no idea how to fix it.

1. Error: TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
2. Error: TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Items'.
3. Error: TS7006: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Tried reading similar questions, tried different fixes, but I keep getting errors. Can anyone show me, or give advice how to fix this kind of errors?

```
interface Items {
  items: any[]
  map: [] 
  //tried to add map like this but got another error - 
  //TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type '[]' has no call signatures.
}

const ItemsList: React.FC<Items> = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const response = Http.get<Items>(url).then(res => setItems(res))
  }, [])

  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => { // all errors here
          return (
            <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item}/>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsList
```

Comment: The various error codes are sometimes difficult to understand, which is why I have made a list of the most common TypeScript errors and their solutions (including TS2532, TS2339 & TS7006): https://typescript.tv/errors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through the comments I added:

```
interface Item {
    id: string;
    // ... add other props here
}

type Items = Item[]

// looks like you're not sending any props to this component so `React.FC` is sufficient
const ItemsList: React.FC = () => {

    // By giving an empty array to `useState`, `items` will always be defined
    // an alternative would be to check if `items` is populated and only render when it is
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // you can give a type to `res` if the response you get here is an array of `Item`s
        // if not, adjust the type accordingly
        Http.get<Items>(url).then((res: Items) => setItems(res))
    }, [])

    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((item) => { // you no longer need to give any types here
                return (
                    <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item}/>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```